# NSAttributedString not changing colour of certain text of NSTextview

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, nsattributedstring, nstextview

I’m using `NSAttributedString` to change the text color of my `NSTextview`. When I want to change the color of a word, the color will not show. Here is my code for more detail

```
let main_string = “Hello World"
let string_to_color = “World"
let range = (main_string as NSString).range(of: string_to_color)
textView.textStorage?.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: NSColor.orange, range: range);
```

When I want the change the text Colour of another string,

```
let main_string = "Hello World"
let string_to_color = "World"
let range = (main_string as NSString).range(of: string_to_color)
textView.textStorage?.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: NSColor.orange, range: range)

let jhgfds = "Lorem Ipsum"
let tdftgdg = "ipsum"
let raresrgsdnge = (jhgfds as NSString).range(of: tdftgdg)
textView.textStorage?.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: NSColor.orange, range: range)
```

This is what happens

[image: This is the image]

Can you please help me with this

Here is my full code…

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTextViewDelegate {
    struct Keys {
        static let noteBook = "noteTaking"
        static let title = "appTitle"
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var livePreviewOn: NSButton!
    var isPaused = true
    var timer = Timer()
    @IBOutlet var textView: NSTextView!
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: NSScrollView!
    /// - Tag: setRepresentedObjectExample
    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
            // Pass down the represented object to all of the child view controllers.
            for child in children {
                child.representedObject = representedObject
            }
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        scrollView.magnification = 1.5
        textView.isAutomaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled = false
        checkSavedText()
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updater), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    @IBAction func pauseResume(sender: AnyObject) {
        if isPaused{
            timer =  Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            isPaused = false
        } else {
            timer.invalidate()
            isPaused = true
        }
    }
    @IBAction func saveBTN(_ sender: Any) {
        saveNoteBookText()
    }
    func saveNoteBookText() {
        defaults.set(textView.string, forKey: Keys.noteBook)
    }
    func checkSavedText() {
        let name = defaults.value(forKey: Keys.noteBook) as? String ?? ""
        textView.string = name
    }
    @objc func update() {
        saveBTN(self)
        webView.loadHTMLString(textView.string, baseURL: nil)
    }
    @objc func updater() {
        saveBTN(self)
        let main_string = "Hello World"
        let string_to_color = "World"
        let range = (textView.textStorage!.string as NSString).range(of: string_to_color)
        textView.textStorage?.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: NSColor.orange, range: range)   
    }
}
```

Comment: `(jhgfds as NSString).range(of: tdftgdg)` or `(main_string as NSString).range(of: string_to_color)`. That's retrieving the range in that particular `main_string` or `jhgfds`, not the range inside `textView.textStorage?.string`.

Comment: So what can I do?

Comment: `let raresrgsdnge = (textView.textStorage?.string as NSString).range(of: tdftgdg)`

Comment: I’m afarid that didn’t work

Comment: And you did the same for `let range = (main_string as NSString).range(of: string_to_color)`? Using `textView.textStorage?.string` instead of `main_string`? What's your full code?

Comment: I’ll edit my question to show the full code. The main code is the the `Updater` in the bottom